# Mirror Maker: supplying broker properties with SSL password encrypted

Tags: encryption, apache-kafka, plaintext, truststore, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Is there a way to supply the consumer.config/producer.config property files having encrypted SSL password? I don't want to store the passwords in plaintext format in the filesystem

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config sourceCluster1Consumer.config --consumer.config sourceCluster2Consumer.config --num.streams 2 --producer.config targetClusterProducer.config --whitelist=".*"
```

Comment: There isn't, AFAIK. if you're trying to protect that information, you need to limit who can access that machine

Comment: kafka 2.0.0 onwards they supported encrypted passwords can be passed in zookeper config. So the need to keep passwords in plaintext is gone. We also handled on all client modules by encrypting the config file and decrypt before starting the producer/consumers. Only issue is with MirrorMaker as it takes only plaintext file

Comment: Tried MirrorMaker 2?

Comment: MirrorMaker 2 didn't have any motivation to handle SSL passwords in plaintext issue looks like. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0

Comment: But it is built on the Connect framework, so it should support this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations and you can use Vault, for example https://github.com/convoyinc/KafkaVaultProvider

Comment: seems like its doable through FileConfigProvider https://rmoff.net/2019/05/24/putting-kafka-connect-passwords-in-a-separate-file-/-externalising-secrets/

Comment: That file is still in plaintext, though

Comment: True but I have a custom implementation of the ConfigProvider to read and decrypt values before returning the ConfigData. 
However for some reason it’s not working yet. I’m using Kafka 2.3 client